# Rename subfolders created by workflow in shrepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Hello I have created a worflow in sharepoint designer which is executed when I add an item in a list automatically creating a library to a part with a folder with four subfolders which works perfectly.  What I do not like is that the subfolders have a default name from the system. I want to know how to change the workflow so that these subfolders can carry the name that I want to assign them
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.  If you are having the workflow create the folder structure automatically when a new item is a separate list is made, how will it know what you want to name the folder without input.  If you want it based off a field from the list, you may need to make a field(n) to fill that info in on the library and them create a workflow there that will rename the folder after it is created based off the data in the field(n).

Comment: if you are right I will do so as you say thank you man